# Deploying azure webjob via git

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

I have a solution containing a .net mvc website, and a webjob.

I deploy using git - so on git push to azure, my website is upgraded. I'm now just adding a console application that is going to be run on a schedule. I'm trying to work out how to deploy this with the website when I `git push`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I know I could create a folder `website\app_data\jobs\triggered\webjob` and copy the files into there (say from a post-build event on the webjob), but that would mean I would need to commit all those files to the git repo for the deploy to pick them up - which would also mean that every time I build, Git would be prompting me to commit them again - ugh.

Is there a nicer way to do this - where I can just push my repo to azure, and it will deploy my website correctly AND my webjob?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this without having to put the actual EXE's and project output into the folder explicitly. This blog post from the Azure Blog documents the workaround to enable Git or command-line deployment of a web application inclusive with WebJobs.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/18/enabling-command-line-or-continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs/

If this doesn't unblock you please post an update and I'll help walk diagnose any other issues you run into. You may also want to update the WebJob publishing NuGet to the most updated one on NuGet here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish/1.0.2

Comment: I've read that blog post, but I see nothing about git deployment. It's also noted [in the kudu doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs) that git deployment of webjobs is possible, but so far I've not had it work.

Comment: nevermind. I had not in fact updated to 1.0.2. Was using 1.0.1. Upgraded and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

As of 9/15/2015, this appears to be as simple as some context menus inside Visual Studio.

If you want your WebJob to automatically deploy whenever your Website is deployed, in Visual Studio you can right-click on the Website and select "Add->Existing Project as Azure WebJob".

More details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#convert), in particular the "Enable automatic WebJobs deployment with a web project" section.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this, but I've got it working now.

It appears that WebJobs.Publish 1.0.2 must be used. 1.0.1 was not working for me. Worked as soon as I updated.

I had also tried adding webjobs.props files as indicated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3f4479b-3502-4fdf-97f9-ababe97ea8fa/webjobs-continuous-deployment-from-vs-online-build?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) by David Ebbo, but that didn't work for 1.0.1 and I've now removed those files and it's working under 1.0.2 without them.

Using WebJobs.Publish creates a webjob-publish-settings.json (in the webjob project) and a webjobs-list.json (in the MVC app) and that would seem to be all that is needed.

Only thing that does not work is creating the schedule for a scheduled job. Continuous and Triggered jobs deploy just fine. There's a thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/058f6546-fc07-4911-b87b-f322560933e6/cannot-create-scheduled-webjob-for-website?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) where David Ebbo mentions that this is a current limitation.